# call callback function from another function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good morning all,

I am trying to call callback function from anther function in angularjs.

My controller look like

```
 function LMSAppController($scope, LMSAppFactory,$http) {

       $scope.branchSearch = function (code){
        $scope.hidbranchcode = code;
        $scope.gridOptions = {};
    }

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        getData: LMSAppFactory.getTableData,    
    };
}
```

When i try to call `gridOptions` function from `branchSearch`, But `gridOptions` not calling.Please suggest where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Edited :

```
function LMSAppFactory($http) {
        var ajaxRequest = 'processRequest.jsp?';
        var branchCode = document.getElementById("hidbranchcodeID").value ;
        alert("branchCode===="+branchCode);

       return {    
            getTableData: getTableData,
       }; 

       function getTableData(params, callback) {
            $http.get(ajaxRequest + 'requestType=getRecords'+params+'&value=10').then(function (response) {
                callback(response.data[1].LMSRecords, response.data[0].LMSRecordsCount);
            });
        }

    }
```

now function is calling.. thanks so much @Jaromanda X sir. But now i am getting "`Error: response.data[1] is undefined`" in console

Comment: `gridOptions` is an object, `gridOptions.getData` is _perhaps_ a function

Comment: Sorry... i am newbie in programming

Comment: calling `$scope.branchSearch` would make `$scope.gridOptions = {};` - so the original object is lost

Comment: if it is a normal function and it does not do anything with scope and the function has no involvement in two way binding,  then no need to mark it as $scope.gridOptions {}, You can write a function like var getData=function{} and directly you can call this function from your grid options

Comment: Thanks @Jaromanda X sir

Comment: Thanks @ Arunprasanth KV sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gridOptions` is not a function. it's an object. When you call `$scope.gridOptions = {};` it will reset the value of `gridOptions` to empty object. if you want to make `gridOptions` function then change it like this.

```
$scope.gridOptions = function(){
  return {
      getData: LMSAppFactory.getTableData
  }
}
```

now call the `gridOptions` function method `getData` like this

```
$scope.branchSearch = function (code){
    $scope.hidbranchcode = code;
    $scope.gridOptions().getData();
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the actual problem, probably the OP is trying to call `$scope.gridOptions.getData()` that suppose to return a promise with data for the view, and they need to display that data. But since we can't see the implementation if the `getData` function inside `LMSAppFactory` then it's too broad to answer

Answer (score 0):

May be your `response.data` is an `array of single object`. like below :

```
var data = [
             {}
           ];
```

Hence, if you will try to access `data[1]` it will return `undefined`.

**DEMO**

```js
var data = [{}];

console.log(data[1]); // undefined
```